# Getting "io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException", while using the same step defination given in trace snippet

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

i have created a cucumber class and trying to modified, while doing so its continously showing the "io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException" again and again when i try to run. I have tried with the steps showing in trace snippet but again the result is same. Here below is the code i am trying

//feature_file
Feature: Application login

Scenario: Home page default login
Given user navigate to login page
When user login into application with "abhishek" and password "abhi234"
Then home page appears
And objects showed are "true"

Scenario: Home page default login
Given user navigate to login page
When user login into application with "Amit" and password "amit345"
Then home page appears
And objects showed are "false"

//stepdefination

```
public class stepdefination2 {

        @Given("^user navigate to login page$")
        public void navigate() {
            System.out.println("welcome");
            throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
        }
        @When("user login into application with {string} and password {string}")
        public void user_login(String arg1, String arg2) {
            System.out.println(arg1);
            System.out.println(arg2);
            throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
        }
        @Then("^home page appears$")
        public void home_page() {
            System.out.println("homepage");
            throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
        }
        @Then("objects showed are {string}")
        public void objects(String obj) {
            System.out.println("objects appeared");
            throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
        }
}
```

//Runner

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features =  "src/test/java/nfeature",
            glue = "stepdefination2"
            )
    public class  TestRun2{
        public void success() {
        System.out.println("test run successfully");
    }
    }
```

Comment: So much question here: proj structure, where are your feature folder and what is their name. pom.xml. Why do you need @RunWith(Cucumber.class) ? Try answer as much as you can so someone can help you.

Comment: The `glue` takes a package name. Not a class name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your @CucumberOptions are not correct and that's why the steps are not found

Answer (score -1):

glue = "stepdefination2" here you need to specify package name under which stepdefinations class files are available. Avoid giving same name for package&class file.

Comment: If possible please provide error screenshot also.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).